# With @nuxtjs/markdownit, how can I resolve a image file in XXX.md file

Tags: nuxt.js, markdown-it

I apply markdown in nuxt vue this way.

```html
<template>
  <div class="doc-container">
    <div v-html="doc"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import doc from './doc.md'
export default {
  name: 'doc',
  data() {
    return {
      doc:doc
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

in `doc.md` file, I need add a image, but how can I resolve the image path?
`http://localhost:3000/guide/~@/assets/images/create.jpg 404 (Not Found)`

```
![image](~@/assets/images/create.jpg)
```

now the problem is

Answer (score 1):

You can drop your images in the `/static` folder. e.g. a file placed here `/static/images/create.jpg` would be mapped to the root like this:

```
![image](/images/create.jpg)
```